# How to activate word highlighting across cells in VScode notebooks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am using Jupyter (.ipynb) notebooks in Visual Studio Code 1.67.0. When I double click on a word/region this highlights all occurrences of that word/region **only in the same cell**. The setting for this in the `settings.json` file is

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {"editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#xxxxxx"}
```

I want the highlighting to happen across **all cells** in the notebook. I have searched for this on SO and Google but have not been able to find any answers. Is it possible to achieve this in VScode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been implemented in [PR #198467](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/198467) and is available since version 1.85.0.