# Word highlighting across cells in VScode notebooks?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When I load an .ipynb file I can highlight a word in an individual cell and VS Code highlights all occurrences of this word in this cell. But it does not highlights the word across cells. Is there a way to configure it to do so?

I searched the Internet and could not find an answer. Which is strange, because this seems to be a big shortcoming.

[How to activate word highlighting across cells in VScode notebooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301605/how-to-activate-word-highlighting-across-cells-in-vscode-notebooks)

No one could answer it here. So I raise it again, because this seems to be an important feature that is missing from VS Code.

Comment: Can you provide some information to help us understand what you actually need? You can also directly propose the design of related functions to developers in [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-JUPYTER). As far as I know, in order to achieve similar functions in the Jupyter web, it is necessary to install plugins instead of the functions provided by itself.